# Non-negative integer?

Tags: c, c++11

I saw this word many times in competitive programming contest. why question setter doesn't use positive integer instead of non-negative integers.Please tell someone what's the reason ?

[https://codeforces.com/][1]

Comment: Because 0 isn't a positive integer?

Comment: Yes, "non-negative" includes zero.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/is-zero-positive-or-negative

Comment: @ChrisTurner not always.

Comment: There is a floating point representation for `-0` but the phrase "Non-negative integer" is a short way to say "Positive integer including zero,"

Comment: In a one's complement system one could argue that "_an integer, positive or zero_" could include `-0` but the wording explicitly excludes the `-0`.

Answer (score 2):

The words “positive integer” apply to the numbers 1, 2, 3,… It does not include 0 because 0 is not positive.

The words “non-negative integer” apply to the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3,… It includes 0 because 0 is not negative.

They mean different things. If a program is required to work for non-negative integers in its inputs, then it must work if an input is zero. If it is only required to work for positive integers in its inputs, then it is not required to work if an input is zero.

In some circumstances, we may distinguish whether a computer representation of a zero has a negative sign or not (or has a positive sign or not), and then one might include +0 as a “positive” number or −0 as a “negative” number, but this generally occurs in specialized subject domains and in contexts where the distinction is clearly stated. So it is not likely a generally programming contest is using “positive” or “negative” in this sense.